# Problem when adding products to the cart. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, addtocart

When I am in a product and I add to the shopping cart 4 units of it (the quantity is just an example) it is added with the amount of "1" and if I add 4 more units, "2" is added instead of 8 !!!

Can somebody help me? I'm newbie in Magento!
Thank you very much in advance.